# Why is there a one-way reputation lane from SO to the network?

Tags: support, reputation, chat, privileges

Why is it that on

- [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com), it counts all your SE reputation (excluding association bonuses), **including MSO and SO**, but on
- [chat.meta.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com) it **only** counts your *MSO reputation*, and on
- [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) it **only** counts your *SO reputation*?

Why does having lots of reputation on SO give you network chat, while having lots of reputation on another network site doesn't benefit you in SO chat? Network chat has site-specific rooms after all.

Comment: Probably because the latter two are entirely site-specific?

Answer (score 3):

Chat.SE is for the entire network. It even has rooms for SO and MSO, though they aren't used much. So it takes into account the network rep.

Chat.SO is pretty large in itself, and they use SO rep because the chat is SO specific.

I don't see a discrepancy here

Comment: Do SO and MSO chat sites simply exist because they were first then?

Comment: @3ventic Sort of, yes. I think MSO chat runs a slightly newer version of the chat software.